# @StaticMetamodel, annotation type not applicable to this type of declaration

Tags: hibernate, maven, glassfish

I'm trying to run a complete project from the book PrimeFaces Starter (Ian Hlavats) looks like a really cool app. You can download from GitHub:

```
https://github.com/ianhlavats/primefaces-starter
```

Watch out to choose the branch that has the "Fix for Java 8 compilationerror" when you import from your IDE.

This app uses Hibernate (I'm more familiar with EclipseLink implementatio), besides I'm kind of new to Maven an this is making a little more complex for me.

I have imported the project in NetBean and all looks fine, except when I build the project there are some additional clases of the Entities that are created. I'm adding a picture of the before and after the build process:

[image]

[image]

Following is an example from one of this clases (City_.java)

[image]

I've been making some modifications in the Persistence.xml file but nothing seems to work. For example by default the provider show up like EclipseLink, I have updated it to Hibernate, have applied some changes form the fix IDE tool, but still the same:

Below is a chunk of code from the log message I'm getting.

```
/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar:
javac option: -proc:only
javac option: -d
javac option: /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/NetBeans/Mac_Netbeans/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/classes
javac option: -s
javac option: /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/NetBeans/Mac_Netbeans/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/src/main/java
diagnostic Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 4.3.11.Final
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_60). Please file a bug at the Java Bug Database (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) after checking the database for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DiagnosticSource.setEndPosTable(DiagnosticSource.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log.setEndPosTable(Log.java:350)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:667)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.executeWithExceptionsHandled(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:447)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
error on execute: error during compilation
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.305 s
Finished at: 2017-10-01T16:55:24-05:00
Final Memory: 31M/364M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:2.1.1:process (process) on project primefaces-webapp: Error executing: error during compilation -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

In order to run the project you'll need to create a mycompany db in mysql. Please find below the script you will need:

```
create database mycompany;
grant all on mycompany.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'user';
```

And that's all the maven project creates the data-source and everything. You'll need GlassFish. I'm not adding more text of the files in order to not to make it so big, but if you need something else please let me know.

Could somebody give me some directions about what I need to do in order to have this project running? Thank you for your support!!

Note. In Eclipse I can build the project and make the war but when import to the GlassFish it pointed out some trouble and would not run the project as well.

Comment: post the error from the stacktrace in google and start from there! It is a compile issue and not glassfish related either

Comment: @Kukeltje Ok man, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turn out to be related to MySQL version. The MYSQL versión creating compatibility issues with the persistence API JPA 2.1 was the following:

```
MySQL 5.7.11 Mysql Community Server (GPL)
```

Then I tried with an older versión:

```
MySQL 5.1.73 Source Distribution
```

And this solved the issue.

Below is the build log:

```
Undeploying ...
cd /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.5.0 /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn clean install
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building primefaces-webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces-mobile/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/primefaces/primefaces-mobile/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Could not transfer metadata org.primefaces:primefaces-mobile:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not transfer metadata org.primefaces:primefaces-mobile:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: unknown error
Failure to transfer org.primefaces:primefaces-mobile:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://repository.primefaces.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of prime-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.primefaces:primefaces-mobile:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer org.primefaces:primefaces-mobile:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of codehaus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.primefaces:primefaces-mobile:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: unknown error

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Deleting /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target
Deleting /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/src/main/java (includes = [**/*_.java], excludes = [])

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (run-annotation-processors-only) @ primefaces-webapp ---
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Compiling 17 source files to /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/classes

--- maven-processor-plugin:2.1.1:process (process) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Source directory: /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/src/main/java added
No processors specified. Using default discovery mechanism.
javac option: -cp
javac option: /Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/3.0.1/maven-plugin-api-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.0.1/maven-model-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/3.0.1/maven-artifact-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/1.4.3.1/sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.3.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.3.1/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.3.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.1/sisu-guice-2.9.1-noaop.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.0.1/maven-core-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/3.0.1/maven-settings-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings-builder/3.0.1/maven-settings-builder-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/3.0.1/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.0.1/maven-model-builder-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-aether-provider/3.0.1/maven-aether-provider-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-spi/1.8/aether-spi-1.8.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-impl/1.8/aether-impl-1.8.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.8/aether-api-1.8.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.8/aether-util-1.8.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.4/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.1/maven-plugin-annotations-3.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.1/plexus-utils-3.0.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/src/main/resources:/Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/classes:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.5/primefaces-3.5.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/primefaces-mobile/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/primefaces-mobile-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.10/javax.faces-2.1.10.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/1.0.10/atmosphere-runtime-1.0.10.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-compat-jbossweb/1.0.10/atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.0.10.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-compat-tomcat/1.0.10/atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.0.10.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7/1.0.10/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.0.10.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/rome/rome/1.0/rome-1.0.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.1/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.9/all-themes-1.0.9.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.11.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.8/slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.1.Final/hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.1/classmate-1.3.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.2/cdi-api-1.2.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/javax/jws/jsr181-api/1.0-MR1/jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/batch/jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/ejb/jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/el/jboss-el-api_3.0_spec/1.0.7.Final/jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.7.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/enterprise/concurrent/jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/faces/jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec/2.2.13/jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.13.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/interceptor/jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/json/jboss-json-api_1.0_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-json-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/management/j2ee/jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/resource/jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/rmi/jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec/1.0.5.Final/jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.5.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/security/jacc/jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/security/auth/message/jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/jms/jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec/1.0.1.Beta1/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.1.Beta1.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/websocket/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec/1.1.1.Final/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec/1.0.4.Final/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/soap/jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec/1.0.3.Final/jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/ws/jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec/2.0.3.Final/jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.11/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.11/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:/Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.22/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar:
javac option: -proc:only
javac option: -d
javac option: /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/classes
javac option: -s
javac option: /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/src/main/java
diagnostic Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 4.3.11.Final

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 3 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ primefaces-webapp ---
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Compiling 78 source files to /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ primefaces-webapp ---

--- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [primefaces-webapp] in [/Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/primefaces-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [/Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/src/main/webapp]
Webapp assembled in [361 msecs]
Building war: /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/primefaces-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping

--- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ primefaces-webapp ---
Installing /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/target/primefaces-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/primefaces-webapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/primefaces-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Installing /Users/mauriciotl/MauricioFiles/Projects/primefaces-starter/primefaces-webapp/pom.xml to /Users/mauriciotl/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/primefaces-webapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/primefaces-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 10.925 s
Finished at: 2017-10-09T15:32:10-05:00
Final Memory: 42M/535M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Errors are gone:

[image]

And now is running:

[image]